# TheBat archive file (tbk) format

Tags: format, email-client

I'd like to write a function to read archived emails from TheBat mail client archive file (.tbk). However, I can't find any specification of the format.

If anyone has this format description or digged it themselves, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Did you tried to open a tbk file with a text editor?

Comment: Is it in plain text or is it encoded in some way? If in plain text, can you c/p a example?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TheBat API Docs](http://www.ritlabs.com/download/files3/the_bat/api/thebat_plugin_api.zip). Even if they don't give you direct low-level format of the file, using them you should be able to write your own functions to read message storage.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I cannot use any third-party APIs in my software. I need to parse files myself.

Answer (score -1):

Try to open the tbk file in a text editor (notepad++ on windows, vi(m) or nano on linux, I don t know what on mac).

Is it plain text?

Yes->Write your parser

No->Write your parser using the API

Comment: Why not open in Internet Explorer or, say it, Movie Maker? Before suggesting a meaningless solution, please try it yourself.